# Can you explain, how to derive this PDF?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[image]

Can someone derive this PDF? Is it inclusion-exclusion principle?

Comment: Please do not use pictures, type them out.

Comment: I've found an answer myself: https://probabilityandstats.wordpress.com/2010/04/04/a-formula-for-the-occupancy-problem/